# Algorithm - maximum distance in tree for all nodes

Tags: algorithm, search, tree

So.. finding the longest path between two nodes in a tree is fairly easy. But what I want is to find the longest path from node `x` to another node in the tree, for all `x`.

This problem can also be expressed in the following way: compute the heights of all rooted trees you can make from a given tree.

One way, of course, is to just do, for all nodes in the tree, a BFS/DFS and remember for each of them the furthest node found. However, this results in O(N<sup>2</sup>). Is it possible to do better?

EDIT: just to recap, my question is **NOT** how to find the longest path in the graph. It is how to find the longest path containing a given node `x` **FOR ALL** nodes `x` in **BETTER THAN** O(N<sup>2</sup>) time complexity, if possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Longest path between 2 Nodes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3124566/longest-path-between-2-nodes)

Comment: @Guido Nope, that's a related but different problem.

Comment: do you want to find N such paths (one for every node) and to have each such path represented by its endpoints?

Comment: Yes, I want to find N such paths, one for every node. How they are represented is not important. I am only interested in the length of each path for every particular node (that is, the height of the tree if it were rooted in that node). I am just wondering if there is a better than O(N^2) algorithm.

Comment: Longest Path of each node to all other nodes will be best possible in O(n^2) only unless you specify some condition like part of tree, etc

Comment: Is the question about paths *from* each node x or about paths *containing* each node x?  You say both.  -1 for now.

Comment: I added some code to my answer. This is a nice little problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's an O(n) algorithm.

Think of the tree as unrooted - just a graph where each node has bi-directional edges that form no cycles.

For a given node p with adjacent nodes, say a_i, we will compute heights Hpa_i.  Height Hpa_i is the height of the subtree *with root p* (i.e. for this part of the algorithm, we temporarily consider a rooted subtree) obtained by considering node a_i to be p's parent.

If you're interested in the longest path from each node to a leaf (your question plus its title leaves doubt about what you're actually trying to compute), it's just max{ Hpa_i for all i }.  The corresponding i value gives the longest path itself.

If on the other hand, you're interested in longest path *through* p, that will be the sum of the largest pair selected from { len(p--a_i) + Ha_ip for all i }, and the two corresponding values of i give the longest path itself.

Thus, if we have the heights for each node, getting the final result is a simple O(n) job.

It remains only to compute the heights for all nodes. For this, start with a special depth-first search. It accepts 2 nodes as parameters.  The first, p, is the node being searched, and the second, q \in {a_i}, is the adjacent node currently bein considered as parent of p.  Let U be a map taking node pairs to heights: (p, q) -> Hpq

```js
function search_and_label(p, q)
  if ((p, q) maps to height Hpq in U ) { return Hpq }
  if (p == null) { add (p, q) -> 0 to U and return 0 }
  let h = max(all x adjacent to p, not equal to q) {
            len(p--x) + search_and_label(x, p)
          }
  add (p, q) -> h to U
  return h
```

Now we can find all the heights.

```js
 Add mappings (p, x)->null to U for all nodes p and adjacent nodes x
 Also add a mapping (p, z)->null to U for all nodes p having < 3 adjacent
 while (U contains a mapping of the form (p, x)->null) 
   search_and_label(p, x) // this replaces the null mapping with a height
```

This will be an O(n) computation, also, because it expends constant work on each edge, and the number of edges in a tree is n-1.

**Code**

It rained today, so here is some code that generates a random tree and labels it with longest path info in O(n) time.  First, a typical output. Each node is labeled with its own number, then the length of a longest path that contains it, followed by numbers of the adjacent nodes on that path. The small edge labels are the height information. First there is the height of the opposite subtree along with the node that's the longest path to leaf in that subtree:

[image: Decorated Tree]

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;

/**
 * An undirected graph. It has a builder that fills the graph with a random
 * unrooted tree. And it knows how to decorate itself with longest path
 * information when it's such a tree.
 */
class Graph {

  /**
   * Edge p--q is represented as edges[p][q]=dq and edges[q][p]=dp, where dq and
   * dp are node data. They describe the respective end of the edge:
   * <ul>
   * <li>dq.len == dp.len, the edge length
   * <li>dq.h is the height of subtree rooted at p with q as parent.
   * <li>dq.next is the child of p (with respect to parent q) rooting the max
   * height subtree.
   * </ul>
   */
  final Map<Node, Map<Node, EdgeData>> edges = new HashMap<>();

  /**
   * A node in the graph.
   */
  static class Node {

    final int id; // Unique node id.
    Node a, b;    // Adjacent nodes on longest path.
    double len;   // Length of longest path.

    Node(int i) {
      this.id = i;
    }
  }

  /**
   * Data associated with one end of an edge in the graph.
   */
  static class EdgeData {

    final double len;  // Edge length.
    Double h;          // Subtree height.
    Node next;         // Next node on max length path to leaf.

    EdgeData(double len) {
      this.len = len;
    }
  }

  /**
   * Add a new node to the graph and return it.
   */
  Node addNode() {
    Node node = new Node(currentNodeIndex++);
    edges.put(node, new HashMap<>());
    return node;
  }
  private int currentNodeIndex = 0;

  /**
   * Add an undirected edge between nodes x and y.
   */
  void addEdge(Node x, Node y, double len) {
    edges.get(x).put(y, new EdgeData(len));
    edges.get(y).put(x, new EdgeData(len));
  }

  /**
   * Decorate subtree rooted at p assuming adjacent node q is its parent.
   * Decorations are memos. No subtree is decorated twice.
   */
  EdgeData decorateSubtree(Node p, Node q) {
    Map<Node, EdgeData> adjacent = edges.get(p);
    EdgeData data = adjacent.get(q);
    if (data.h == null) {
      data.h = 0.0;
      for (Map.Entry<Node, EdgeData> x : adjacent.entrySet()) {
        if (x.getKey() != q) {
          double hNew = x.getValue().len + decorateSubtree(x.getKey(), p).h;
          if (hNew > data.h) {
            data.h = hNew;
            data.next = x.getKey();
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return data;
  }

  /**
   * Decorate node p with longest path information. Decorations are memos. No
   * node nor its associated subtrees are decorated twice.
   */
  Node decorateNode(Node p) {
    if (p.a == null) {
      double ha = 0.0, hb = 0.0;
      for (Map.Entry<Node, EdgeData> x : edges.get(p).entrySet()) {
        double hNew = x.getValue().len + decorateSubtree(x.getKey(), p).h;
        // Track the largest two heights and corresponding subtrees.
        if (hNew > ha) {
          p.b = p.a;
          hb = ha;
          p.a = x.getKey();
          ha = hNew;
        } else if (hNew > hb) {
          p.b = x.getKey();
          hb = hNew;
        }
      }
      p.len = ha + hb;
    }
    return p;
  }

  /**
   * Decorate the entire tree. This isn't necessary if the lazy decorators are
   * used as accessors.
   */
  void decorateAll() {
    for (Node p : edges.keySet()) {
      decorateNode(p);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Random tree builder. Parameters are a maximum edge length, tree radius in
   * number of edges, and partitions p[k] giving probabilities of branching with
   * degree k.
   */
  class RandomTreeBuilder {

    final Random gen = new Random();
    final long seed;
    final float[] partitions;
    final int maxLen;
    final int radius;

    RandomTreeBuilder(long seed, float[] partitions, int maxLen, int radius) {
      this.seed = seed;
      this.partitions = partitions;
      this.maxLen = maxLen;
      this.radius = radius;
    }

    private void growTree(Node p, int radius) {
      if (radius > 0) {
        float random = gen.nextFloat();
        float pSum = 0f;
        for (float partition : partitions) {
          pSum += partition;
          if (random < pSum) {
            return;
          }
          Node q = addNode();
          addEdge(p, q, 1 + gen.nextInt(maxLen));
          growTree(q, radius - 1);
        }
      }
    }

    /**
     * Build a tree in the graph. Any existing nodes and edges are erased.
     */
    void build() {
      if (seed != 0) {
        gen.setSeed(seed);
      }
      edges.clear();
      Node p = addNode();
      Node q = addNode();
      addEdge(p, q, 1 + gen.nextInt(maxLen));
      growTree(p, radius);
      growTree(q, radius);
    }
  }

  class TreePrinter {

    PrintStream stream;

    TreePrinter(PrintStream stream) {
      this.stream = stream;
    }

    /**
     * Print graph in the GraphViz DOT language.
     */
    void print() {
      stream.println("graph tree {");
      stream.println(" graph [layout = twopi overlap=false ranksep=1.7]");
      Node p = edges.keySet().iterator().next();
      Node q = edges.get(p).keySet().iterator().next();
      printEdge(p, q);
      print(p, q);
      print(q, p);
      for (Node x : edges.keySet()) {
        printNode(decorateNode(x));
      }
      stream.println("}");
    }

    /**
     * Print edge {@code p--q} in the GraphViz DOT language.
     */
    private void printEdge(Node p, Node q) {
      EdgeData dq = decorateSubtree(p, q);
      EdgeData dp = decorateSubtree(q, p);
      stream.format(" n%d--n%d [label=\"%.0f\" fontsize=8 "
          + "headlabel=\"%.0f:%s\" taillabel=\"%.0f:%s\"]\n",
          p.id, q.id, dq.len,
          dp.h, dp.next == null ? "-" : dp.next.id,
          dq.h, dq.next == null ? "-" : dq.next.id);
    }

    /**
     * Print node p in the GraphViz DOT language.
     */
    private void printNode(Node p) {
      stream.format(" n%d [ label=\"%d (%.0f:%s-%s)\" fontsize=10 ]\n",
          p.id, p.id, p.len,
          p.a == null ? "-" : p.a.id, p.b == null ? "-" : p.b.id);
    }

    /**
     * Print the sub-tree rooted at node p, treating node q as its parent.
     */
    private void print(Node p, Node q) {
      for (Node x : edges.get(p).keySet()) {
        if (x != q) {
          printEdge(p, x);
          print(x, p);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    PrintStream stream = args.length > 0
        ? new PrintStream(new File(args[0]))
        : System.out;
    Graph graph = new Graph();
    graph.new RandomTreeBuilder(42L, new float[]{0.3f, 0.1f, 0.3f, 0.2f}, 10, 5)
        .build();
    graph.new TreePrinter(stream).print();
  }
}
```

Comment: Is len(p--a) the length of the edge (p, a)?  If so, then I think "the largest pair selected from { len(p--a) + Hap, len(p--b) + Hbp, len(p--c) + Hcp }" is not what you're looking for, since e.g. the first term, "len(p--a) + Hap" seems to be describing the length of a *tree* (not a path) that consists of a path of length Hap which goes through the vertices b, p, and c, plus the edge (p, a) (so that vertex p has degree 3).

Comment: @j_random_hacker Hap is the height of the subtree rooted at a (i.e. the longest path from a to a leaf that does not use edge a--p).  Adding len(p--a) gives total maximum distance to a leaf starting from p and using edge (p--a).  I'll write code if I get time.

Comment: Thanks!  I see now that I was confusing Hpa with Hap.  I think your solutions works to solve both the form of the problem where we want to find the longest path *containing* each vertex x, and by simply choosing the largest of the 3 items in that set (instead of the sum of the largest 2), it would solve the version where we want the longest path *beginning* at each vertex x (OP isn't clear which one s/he wants). :)

Comment: One more point: It took me a while to understand that the line `if ((p, x) maps to height Hpx in U )` is just checking whether (p, x) has already had its height computed and stored in the memo table or not (as opposed to actually comparing the result of the lookup to some somehow-computed value of Hpx).  You could possibly make this a little clearer.

Comment: @j_random_hacker yeah i'll certainly refine when I get a minute.

Comment: I haven't yet had the time to understand the solution fully, but I am conflicted about the "each node has 3 or fewer bi-directional edges". That kind of graph does not cover all trees, does it? A node in a tree can have more than 3 children. Does this mean that the algorithm provided will only solve the problem for a certain family of trees?

Comment: @NuNunu Thanks. I had binary trees in mind while constructing the example and algorithm, but it works fine with trees of all arities.  I edited the answer.

Comment: @j_random_hacker I added code. It's interesting to watch it work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution..

**First Pass** recursively go over all nodes and set `M` (the max depth) for each node in the tree.

```
M(X) = 0 IF X DOES NOT EXIST
EXIST(X) = 1 IF X EXISTS, 0 OTHERWISE

M = MAX(EXIST(LEFT) + M(LEFT), EXIST(RIGHT) + M(RIGHT))
```

**Second Pass** recursively go over all nodes and set `R` (the maximum distance through) any root in the tree (a root is a node that has at least 1 child), by taking the sum of the max 2 values off the children then adding the distance of a path if it exist on either child.

```
IF SUM(EXIST(..)) = 0 THEN R = 0
IF SUM(EXIST(..)) = 1 THEN R = X.M + 1 WHERE EXIST(X) = 1

R = SUM(MAX2(x,y: x.M >= y.M >= ..)) + EXIST(x) + EXIST(y)

R: the node max distance through.
M: the node max depth.
```

**Final Pass** recursively go over all nodes and find the maximum value of `R` in the tree.

```
R(NULL) = 0
R(THIS) = R OF THE CURRENT NODE

S = MAX(R(THIS), S(CHILD1), .. S(CHILDX))
```

**Complexity**

```
TIME = N + N + N = 3N

TIME ~ O(N)
```

Comment: You seem to be trying to compute the overall longest path in the tree, which the OP makes clear s/he is not asking for.  To adapt this to find the longest path beginning at each node x (or containing each node x; the OP is unclear here) I think you need to also consider paths that go back up through the parent node.

Comment: @j_random_hacker you're right, I misread it. it's going to be more difficult, I'll need more time to rethink it and try to find something in common between nodes so I can fit it in O(n). I'm already accounting for the link with parent by doing `+ EXIST(x)`

Answer (score -1):

Your question reduces to finding the longest path in a tree. This is also called the diameter of a tree.

This is a well researched topic and there are plenty of resources that provide an O(n) algorithm where n is the number of nodes in the graph.

See [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11263/longest-path-in-an-undirected-tree-with-only-one-traversal) and [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/22855/algorithm-to-find-diameter-of-a-tree-using-bfs-dfs-why-does-it-work)

Comment: Could you please explain how it reduces to longest path in a tree? I already know how to find the diameter of the tree, but this is not what I asked. I began my question with "So.. finding the longest path between two nodes in a tree is fairly easy. But what I want is...."