# Sum of maximum flow between every pair of vertices of a tree

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree, depth-first-search, max-flow

Given a undirected tree with `N` vertices numbered from 1 to N. Each edge tree has some capacity. Find the sum of maximum flow between all possible pair of vertices. There exist only one way to go between any two vertices.
Find the sum of maximum flow between all possible pair of vertices.

For eg: In given tree with 3 edges 
`1 2 5` 
`2 3 6` 
Edges between node 1 and node 2 with capacity 5, node 2 and node 3 with capacity 6. 
`Output - 32`

`(1,2) = (2,1) = 5` 
`(1,3) = (3,1) = 5` 
`(2,3) = (3,2) = 6` 
Therefore output is `(5+5+6)*2 = 32`

My Approach-

1. `Sort` edges based on edge_capacity
2. While `edge_list` is `not empty`: remove edge with minimum capacity

   - count number of nodes on `left` and `right` of this edge. Do DFS for node count
   - Add (`left_count` * `right_count` * `edge_capacity`) to the answer.
3. return `answer*2`.

Time complexity is O(n<sup>2</sup>). This solution gives TLE.
 
How can we further reduce the time complexity? 
My code-

```
def dfs(node):
    count = 1
    visited = set()
    stack = [node]
    while stack:
        vertex = stack.pop()
        if vertex not in visited:
            visited.add(vertex)
            stack.extend(set(nodes[vertex]) - visited)
    return len(visited)

for _ in range(int(raw_input())):   # Iterate for multiple test cases
    MOD = 1000000007
    edges = []
    n = int(raw_input())            # number of vertices
    nodes = [set() for _ in range(n)]
    for __ in range(n-1):           # read input for number of edges
        edges.append(map(int, raw_input().split()))
        nodes[edges[-1][0]-1].add(edges[-1][1]-1)    
        nodes[edges[-1][1]-1].add(edges[-1][0]-1)
        edges[-1][0]-=1; edges[-1][1]-=1; 
    edges.sort(key=lambda x: x[2])

    answer = 0
    for i in range(len(edges)):
        weight = edges[i][2]
        x, y = edges[i][0], edges[i][1]
        nodes[x].remove(y)
        nodes[y].remove(x)
        left_count = dfs(x)
        right_count = dfs(y)
        answer += ((left_count*right_count*weight)%MOD)
    print (answer*2)%MOD
```

Link to the original problem-
[Spoj-Flow on Tree](http://www.spoj.com/problems/PRJAN15E/)

**Updates**

Constraints-

1. Number of test cases - 10
2. 1 <= N <= 10<sup>5</sup>  (number of vertices in each test case)
3. Capacities of each edge will be non-negative and no more than 10<sup>6</sup>.
4. The total number of vertices among all test cases will be less than 5*10<sup>5</sup>.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of running two new DFSes each time to count subtree sizes, run a smarter DFS just once that computes, for each edge uv, the number of nodes in the subtree rooted at u that is formed when the edge uv is deleted.  (Note that you will need to compute this value for both uv and vu.)

For a way to compute these node counts in linear time, see [this nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36394797/47984).

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to maximize the value of N for the vertices with highest Degree.

```
    public static int highestSum(int N, int[] A, int[] B) {

    // Initialize a DP array to save the Degree of Each Vertex of Graph
    int[] dp = new int[N + 1];
    int sum = 0;
    // Iterate over A and B and increase the index value in DP array
    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        dp[A[i]]++;
        dp[B[i]]++;
    }
    // Sort the array so that we can assign max value of N to Vertex with maximum
    // //degree
    Arrays.sort(dp);
    for (int j = dp.length - 1; j > 0; j--) {
        sum += dp[j] * j;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another fun approach based on [Kruskal's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm) and [Union Find](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure):

```
algorithm Kruskal(G) is
    res := 0
    size := {v:1 for v in G.V}
    for each (u,v) in G.E ordered by weight(u,v) decreasing do
        u' := FIND-SET(u)
        v' := FIND-SET(v)
        res += weight(u,v) * size[u'] * size[v']
        w' := UNION(u', v')
        size[w'] = size[u'] + size[v']
    return res
```

By combining across large edges first, we always know that the new edge we are studying is the smallest in the subtree.

It's essentially linear time if your edges are already ordered by weight.

Answer (score 0):

Idea is to use DSU by sorting the edges in descending order and find number of paths for each union.

More interesting and harder version appeared in Facebook Hackercup 2021, Round 1, where you have to do the same thing but for each edge being disconnected. Link to the problem: https://www.facebook.com/codingcompetitions/hacker-cup/2021/round-1/problems/C